# Showing relationships inside the model

Tags: python, django

This is a model for my MCQ app. Is there a way to show relationship inside this particular model that `answer` belongs to one of the options and there should be only one right option

```
class Question(models.Model):
  quiz_question=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
  option1=models.CharField(max_length=500)
  option2=models.CharField(max_length=500)  
  option3=models.CharField(max_length=500)
  option4=models.CharField(max_length=500)
  option5=models.CharField(max_length=500)
  answer=models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Always 5 Options

Add another field that points to the right option. For example, you could use a ChoiceField that has those choices:

```
(1, 'option1')
(2, 'option2')
(3, 'option3')
(4, 'option4')
(5, 'option5')
```

This solution is okay when there are always ever these 5 options.

### Free amount of options

In this case, don't specify options as different fields but use ManyToManyFields and ForeignKeyFields:

```
class Option(Model):
    text = TextField(unique=True)

class Question(Model):
    quiz_question = TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    answer = TextField()
    options = ManyToManyField(Option)
    selected_option = ForeignKeyField(Option)
```

Add a validator or `clean_selected_option` method that controls that the selected option is one of `options`.

Or use a `through` model that has an additional column `selected`:

```
class QuestionOption(Model):
    option = ForeingKeyField(Option)
    question = ForeignKeyField(Question)
    selected = BooleanField(default=False)

    def clean_selected(self):
        # make sure only one option per question is selected

class Question(Model):
    quiz_question = TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    answer = TextField()
    options = ManyToManyField(Option, through=QuestionOption)
```